# Blender Game Engine Not Rendering Objects Properly

Tags: camera

So I made a simple blender game engine with a controllable character using WASD and mouse.  I added a Suzanne mesh and it will not render properly.
However, when I render from outside the camera in the game engine, the Suzanne mesh renders properly.  The 'game' is meant to be played from the first person.  The 1st person perspective camera is parented by the box and follows it, the camera is inside the box.

As you move around in 1st person, the object renders in different ways really fast, resulting in a flash, GIF here: https://media.giphy.com/media/WwpazKMWcgWTYJbps8/giphy.gif
[image: as you move, it constantly changes (from 1st person)]
This one keeps looking like this no matter where I move the character
[image: it doesn't move (external shot)]
If you know what I can do to fix this, please leave an answer, it would be greatly appreciated.  Feel free to ask questions about how I set it up, I would be happy to help!

Comment: It seems like some graphics system issue... did you try to update drivers to latest versions?